# How to properly pipe find with grep and cp in this use case

Tags: linux, find, grep

I am interested in recursively grepping for a string in a directory for a pattern and then cp'ing the matching file to a destination directory. I thought I could do something like the following, but it doesn't seem to make sense with linux's find tool:

`find . -type f -exec grep -ilR "MY PATTERN" | xargs cp /dest/dir`

Is there a better way of going about this? Or a way that even works would be a solid start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do `man xargs` and look at the `-I` flag.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -ilR "MY PATTERN" {} \; | xargs -I % cp % /dest/dir/
```

Also, `find` expects a `\;` or `+` after the `-exec` flag.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm getting the error `find: missing argument to `-exec`

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` reads its standard input and puts them at the end of the command to be executed.  As you've written it, you would end up executing

```
cp /dest/dir sourcefile1 sourcefile2 sourcefile3
```

which is backwards from what you want.

You could use the `-I` option to specify a placeholder for `xargs`, like this: `xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /dest/dir`.

Also, `find` takes care of the recursion, so your `grep` does not need `-R`.

Final solution:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -il "MY PATTERN" '{}' + | xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' /dest/dir
```

Comment: I commented below also, does -exec need to be terminated? I'm getting `find: missing argument to `-exec`, not sure where I'd put `{} \;` when there is a pipe to xargs involved.

Comment: Thanks, corrected.  I've used `+` instead of `\;` for efficiency, since GNU find supports it.

Comment: @imaginative There is no fixed "above" and "below" on Stack Exchange; the relative position of posts change both because of voting, activity and user preference (see the "active", "oldest", "votes" sorting tabs just below the question). Hence, it is best to be explicit about which answer you refer to (by linking or at least specifying the full name of the answerer works well in my experience). For example, for me the only "below" currently is Neil H Watson's unvoted and uncommented answer. I'm *guessing* you are referring to Sammitch's answer, which is now on top.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need find.  Recursive grep:

```
grep -rl "MY PATTERN" .
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the examples above takes into account the possibility of `grep`'s `-l` generating duplicated results (files with the same name, but in different places), and therefore `find`'s `exec`'s hook overwriting files in the destination directory.

An attempt to solve this:

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── bar
│   ├── baz
│   │   └── file
│   └── file
├── destdir
└── file

3 directories, 3 files

$ while read a; do mv $a foo/destdir/$(basename $a).$RANDOM; done < <(grep -rl content foo)

$ tree foo
foo
├── bar
│   └── baz
└── destdir
    ├── file.10171
    ├── file.10842
    └── file.25404

3 directories, 3 files
```